# Got 403 error in accessing all files in media directory which have dynamic generated subdirectory users, and maindalali

Tags: django, nginx, permissions, media

I am using Django + react, all are deployed on the same EC2 server, IAM USING Daphne as ASGI server and nginx as reverse proxy... The problem is only on access and not on serving media like Images, problem show in browser even with commands that access to ... .jpg or .txt is denied with error 403

I tried to access user profile for example..no problem but image within user profile not load and console.log that 403 permission error, i expected image to be visible like in local development ....
my nginx for media is
[nginx conf for media](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKNjc.png)

Comment: How does your Nginx Configuration look like ?

Comment: I added image for my nginx conf for my media